# Is there a way to set an automatic closing date for a job position in Odoo?

Tags: date, odoo, jobs, odoo-8

I am fairly new to Odoo development and am now trying to set an automatic closing date for a new job position being created. I can't find this feature.

What would be the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in two ways.
1) using onchange, suppose job opening date is 30-jun-2015, and you want to close the job after 10 days, then using onchange calculate the value and populate it in closed date

2) Using Openerp crons, you can configure a cron, and in the cron method apply your required conditions, and calculate the closing date, and set the interval for the cron,

** Note that by using functional field, the function will be called every time the record is being accessed.